# How to play video from stream link or youtube link on webview android?

Tags: webview, video-streaming, android-webview, html5-video, android-youtube-api

I searched for it a lot but don't have a reasonable answer.How to play video from stream link or youtube link on webview android.i used tag video or iframe but occur some bugs:
-when click full screen video 'll stop and can't play again.
-when click back button for finish fragment,that contain webview,video still playing

Answer (score -1):

Please see the "HTML5 Video support" section at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html for some methods that you must implement.

When the video continues playing after finishing the fragment, are you destroying the WebView?

Comment: in ondestroy of fragment, i call doetroy webview.however video still play.i kill app,video still play.i have to clear ram memory, it stop.